# cant import StandardScalar class in Python for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I cant import `StandardScaler` class in my python Program. By the way, I am using Spyder and I don't understand where I'm getting stuck. It shows the following error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-85a91f244dd6>", line 25, in <module>
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScalar

ImportError: cannot import name 'StandardScalar'
```

Comment: `StandardScalar` --> `StandardScaler`

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its StandardScaler as because your spelling is incorrect so it produces error.
if in future when you stuck in any problem then use dir function to see all methods and modules .
for eg-
print(dir(sklearn))